# Windows cannot search my external hard drive whilst it is indexing it

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive, search

Windows cannot search my external hard drive whilst it is indexing it. If I want my hard drive to be indexed on Windows, I can only search it after it has been indexed.

I don't want to remove my external hard drive from my index so I can search it. Surely there's a way to search a hard drive whilst it's being indexed.

So how can I search my external hard drive whilst it is indexing?

Comment: Use the second method I described of Searching using Windows Explorer until indexing is done.

Comment: I can't see your answer. You appear to of deleted it.

Comment: Yes, I delete downvoted answers for what I consider to be obvious reasons. From that answer  "You can also use Windows Explorer, go to a main folder, top right and Search that way. That will search the folder you pick, indexed or not."

Comment: Or use a third-party search tool. Agent Ransack performs a search without index, and allowing use of regex, which Windows does not https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/ . Also, look at DocFetcher for a different indexed search. http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html , which shows indexing progress.

Comment: @John Your comment is not helpful. If I didn't have problems searching with Windows Explorer, I wouldn't be asking my question here. Windows Explorer **cannot** search external hard drives **whilst** it's being indexed. You do not understand my question. Anyway, I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. Also you shouldn't delete downvoted answers as other people might find it useful. If your answer does not answer the question, a moderator will delete it.

Comment: I can search external drives using non-indexed Search any time so I do not know why that does not work for you. Something apparently wrong with the operating system. I did understand what was you were trying to achieve and was coming from the perspective of a correctly working system.

Comment: I can search external drives non-indexed as well. My question already states this. This is not what my question is asking. My question is asking how to search external hard drives on Windows while the indexing is happening. Not a completed index, not having no index, but while the index is processing.